# Python Minimum is blank

Tags: python, minimum

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
lines = f.read().split('\n')
a= max(lines)
print a
f.close()
```

The above code gets me a maximum from my data file but when I try:

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
lines = f.read().split('\n')
a= min(lines)
print a
f.close()
```

I get a blank return, Its like the minimum in the file is a blank space. Why is this? How can I get a minimum reading?

The file looks like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Did you know that `"10" < "2"`? If you're comparing strings that contain numbers, you need to convert them to numbers before, or your results may be incorrect. So for examples use `a = max(lines, key=int)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have blank line in your file. To discard those values use a generator expression or list comprehension

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
if lines:
    a = min(int(line) for line in lines if line.strip())
    print a
f.close()
```

Comment: Actually, it's _not_ a blank line in the file per se, more an artefact of splitting on newline, meaning that there will be empty data after the _last_ newline in the file, even for a file with no blank lines, like `A\nB\nC\n`. Your code still works, I just think it would be a good idea to clarify that bit.

Answer (score 4):

The error as aforesaid is because of `\n`... You can try this

```
with open("file.txt") as f: 
    print(min(int(i) for i in f if i.strip()))
```

It is a generator exp coupled with a function cal ... Though complicated, it is smaller in size

Comment: No. Should be `min(int(i) for i in f if i.strip())`

Comment: @dawg It works perfectly. Thanks ... (I soo wanna call you as `Yo! dawg` .. :( ..)

Comment: Be aware that `bool(' ')` is True but `bool(' '.strip())` is False.

Comment: This is the best way, it also avoids loading the entire file into memory with `.readlines()`

Answer (score 2):

A first guess may be that your file actually has an empty/blank line at the end, that would cause the "minimum" to be blank.

However, even with a file with *no* extraneous newline, you'll still have the problem.

If you split the stream `AA\nBB\nCC\n` (a normal file) with newline as the separator, the final newline will give you an empty element, the same way that splitting `AA,BB,CC,` on a comma would:

```
['AA','BB','CC','']
```

In other words, there's an *empty* field after the final separator.

There's a couple of ways to fix that, such as using:

```
lines = f.read().split('\n')[:-1]
```

or, alternatively:

```
a = min(lines[:-1])
```

if you know the final newline will be there (which it generally *should* be for normal text files).

If you want to handle cases where the file may *not* necessarily have a terminating newline and may also be empty, you can use this instead:

```
lines = f.read().split('\n')
if len(lines) == 0:
    minline = "" # or None if you prefer
else:
    if lines[-1] == '':
        lines = lines[:-1]
    minline = min(lines)
# Use minline here
```

And, as a final note, `min/max` give you lexicographical sorting, which would sort the number 1 through 10 inclusive as:

```
1,10.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9
```

If you want *numeric* sorting (and you know all lines have valid numbers), use:

```
min(mylist,key=int)
```

Comment: There's no need to load the entire file into memory (`f.read()`) just to find the `min` item

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to change your code  like below.

```
f = open("file", "r")
print(min((i for i in f.read().split('\n') if i), key=float))
f.close()
```

Execution:

```
$ cat file
0.5
1
2
3
4
5
10.1
10.2
$ python3 file.py
0.5
```